# How to run an IntelliJ Kotlin project with multiple files and Maven dependencies using a batch script?

Tags: kotlin, maven, batch-file, intellij-idea

I have a Kotlin IntelliJ project with multiple files, including some in subdirectories, and two Maven dependencies: apache.poi and apache.poi.ooxml. I managed to run the project with a single file using a batch script, but when I add more files to the project, I get unresolved reference errors.

Here is my code for Main.kt:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
    worker.prepareXlsxToAirtable()
    println("Program is finished")
}
```

This works with the following batch script when I comment out the worker.prepareXlsxToAirtable() line:

```
cd C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\AppsApiScript
call kotlinc src\main\kotlin\Main.kt -d bin
kotlin -cp bin MainKt
pause
```

However, when I include the worker.prepareXlsxToAirtable() line, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\AppsApiScript>call kotlinc src\main\kotlin\Main.kt -d bin
src\main\kotlin\Main.kt:3:5: error: unresolved reference: worker
    worker.prepareXlsxToAirtable()
    ^
Hello World!
Program is finished

C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\AppsApiScript>
```

I have followed this Stack Overflow question to run a single file, but it does not cover running a project with multiple files and Maven dependencies: [How to run Kotlin IntelliJ IDEA project from a Windows bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154645/how-to-run-kotlin-intellij-idea-project-from-windows-bat-file)?

How can I modify my batch script to run the project with multiple files and Maven dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are missing a Build Tool.  There are two major ones you can use with Kotlin: Gradle and Maven.  With these it will take away all of this problem for you and you can compile and execute in one step.

Read https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html

Here's how you would run:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.myorg.App"
```